# Discord.JS, Node.JS, Uber-API Messages in For loop not sending

Tags: node.js, geocoding, uber-api

I'm trying to write a Discord bot that when It gets the address replies the products. And so it doesn't reply only the first product I wrote a for loop that loops through all products and replies in a new message the Product name, Description, and capacity. But nothing is happening on the server. No messages no anything. This is the part I from my code that is supposed to reply and in the meantime convert the address into latitude and longitude get the products and reply them

```
  geocoder.geocode(address, function(err, res) {
console.log(res);
var latitude = res[0]["latitude"]
var longitude = res[0]["longitude"]
uber.products.getAllForLocation(latitude,longitude, function (err, res) {
  if (err){
    console.error(err);
    bot.reply(message,err);
  }
  else {
    console.log(res)

    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      bot.reply(message, i + "." + res['products'][i][' display_name'] + " " + res['products'][i]['description'] + " " + "Capacity: " + " " + res['products'][i]['capacity']);
    }
  };

    });
    });
```

For Discord I use Discord.JS but there isn't a tag yet for that service

Comment: What does it log to your console? Is there any service available for your location?

Comment: It prints the list of products available for that Address in JSON and if there is an error It outputs it and sends that

Comment: Sounds like the problem is related to the Discord.JS lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to know the reason it's failing to send the message I would suggest catching the promis rejection from `bot.reply()`
Something like

`bot.reply().catch((error)=>{console.log(error)};`

Then check your console for the reason it's failing to send.